# Content-type `application/xml` is displaying flattened text (loosing XML structure) in Firefox

Tags: xml, http, firefox

(Basically it is the same question as [Why XML file is not rendered properly in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10649253/6607497), but no answer seems to apply for me)

I wrote a simple test HTTP server that sends XML output (as `application/xml`).
However Firefox 78.13.0esr displays it as plain text, i.e. it leaves out all the element tags and spaces.
Anyway when viewing the "page source" the XML is displayed correctly.

So I wonder whether it is a bug in Firefox, or whether my test server is doing something wrong (or I misunderstood something).
The only extension being installed is the Adobe Acrobat PDF extension.

Here is the response header:

```http
HTTP/1.1 200 All bits are up
Date: Fri, 03 Sep 2021 06:02:29 GMT
Server: libwww-perl-daemon/6.01
Content-Length: 604
Content-Type: application/xml
Charset: utf-8
```

Here is the content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MonitoringOutput id="foo-test" version="0.1">
  <description>a simple test only</description>
  <exit_code>0</exit_code>
  <status_string>OK</status_string>
  <info_string>response_time(passwd:nagios) is 0.006 (0)</info_string>
  <perf_string> passwd_nagios=0.006;0;0;0</perf_string>
  <perf_data count="1">
    <sample label="passwd_nagios">
      <label>passwd_nagios</label>
      <value>0.006</value>
      <thresholds>
        <warn end="0"/>
        <crit end="0"/>
      </thresholds>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
  </perf_data>
</MonitoringOutput>
```

Finally this is what Firefox displays:

```text
a simple test only 0 OK response_time(passwd:nagios) is 0.006 (0) passwd_nagios=0.006;0;0;0 passwd_nagios 0.006
```

Note: If I send JSON as `application/json`, then Firefox displays it nicely, allowing to collapse parts of it even.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an extension and there are apparently a ton of them that do it.  There's another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649253/why-xml-file-is-not-rendered-properly-in-firefox) all about it.  In my case it is the "SwipeToNavigate" add-on.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the content-type to text/xml as this is working for me on another page

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: First, it did not make a difference (Did you try it with my example?). Second I'm beginning to believe that it is a feature of Firefox, to ignore all markup when there is no XSL stylesheet.